# AutoMapper Keep Value on Destination Object if doesen't exists on the Source object,

Tags: c#, automapper, .net-7.0

How can I keep the values ​​in the destination object if they are not present in the source class?

E.g.:
I have two classes, DTOPage and PDFPage.
In the PDFPage, template loaded from a Database, I have positional data like X, Y, Width and Height but
the client specifies only data like name, surname and fiscal code.
When i Map DTOPage into PDFPage the X, Y, Width and Height are null.

```
public class PDFPage
{
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public List<Field>? Fields { get; set; }
}

public class DTOPage
{
    public List<DTOField>? Fields { get; set; }
}
```

I tried with :

```
CreateMap<DTOPage,PDFPPage>().ForMember(x => x.Width,
           config => config.UseDestinationValue()).ForMember(x=>x.Height,config => config.UseDestinationValue());
```

But it doesn't work, and the Width and height, previously settled, are null.

Comment: *X, Y, Width and Height are null*, it is impossible. Those properties are integer type but not nullable, so by default it will be 0 but not null. And can you show how your way to map the data, something like: `var dest = _mapper.Map<PDFPPage>(src);`. Do you create new instance or use existing instance for `dest`?

Comment: I believe the problem comes from the Pages property which is a List<Page>.
I've read that automapper always instantiates a new list when the attribute is a List.

I need to figure out how to train the mapper or, like I did, do the mapping manually.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `width` and `height` cannot be null (0 by default).

Then, if you only want to map the Fields property, you need to create a mapping between `DTOField` and `Field` :

```
CreateMap<DTOField, Field>();
```

Add an ignore statement to the page mapper :

```
CreateMap<DTOPage,PDFPPage>()
.ForMember(x => x.Width, config => config.Ignore()) // same for width, x, y
```

I understand that you don't want your properties x, y.. to be overwritten, so you need to map to an existing object as follows :

```
_mapper.Map<DTOPage, PDFPage>(yourDtoPage, yourExistingPdfPage);
```

Comment: Thanks, 
using this instruction:
_mapper.Map<DTOPage, PDFPage>(yourDtoPage, yourExistingPdfPage);

solve the problem.